# C++ getenv and setenv

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to build a simple shell that can add, remove, get, and print the environment. I understand that a copy of the environment from the parent process comes through the int main() in a C++ program, but does that copy of the environment never get updated after a setenv call?

Do I have to manage the environment myself and keep a copy of the environment in my shell, because when I do a setenv call and then print the environment; my variable and value are not there. If I do a getenv call, the variable is still 
 there. In the end I'm missing something that is really simple. Thanks

This is not a homework project, but here is an example of what I am talking about.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[], char * envp[]) {

    setenv("My_Example", "For StackOverFlow because I'm dumb. Thanks.", 0);

    for (char **env = envp; *env != 0; env++)
       std::cout << *env << std::endl;

    std::cout << "---------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value: " << getenv("My_Example") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: program run on their on environment I think thats why you are setenv is not mutated to the terminal .

Comment: Nobody can really see that your program actually works just fine.  What is not obvious is that updating the environment of the parent process of your program is rocket science.  Your shell needs to support integrated commands (like SET) that it executes itself instead of passing the job to a process.

Comment: How can no body see that my program works just fine? I tested it and everything worked well on Ubuntu and should work on Unix. Also setenv does not update the "parents" environment, it updates the current process that my shell is running in. Okay, my shell has to manage the environment itself. Thanks

Comment: @AaronV77: The standard advice on StackOverflow is to show both **what you see** and **what you expected**. We're not understanding your problem, because **what we see is what we expect, but we may expect other things than you do**.

Comment: @MSalters thank you for clearing up the issue. I was just thinking that if everyone did the example that they would see that the environment variable was not in the environment when they printed it out, but I should've mentioned this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`envp` is a **copy** of the environment at the time `main` was invoked.  As soon as you call `setenv`, the environment has changed and the corresponding entry in `envp` is out of date.

Comment: So the question is do I have to manage my own environment then or is there a way to get the updated version of the environment? Thanks.

Comment: @AaronV77  You can get values of current env of the process by using getenv() function. Is there need to get list of all env variables?

Comment: @SKi the reason for printing all the environment variables out was to support the printenv command that most Linux and Unix machines have. Thanks

Comment: @AaronV77 - use the `envp` parameter passed in to get the initial environment. Since it's your process, the environment won't change unless your code calls `setenv`. If you need to keep a running table of all env name/value pairs, I would suggest using `envp` to build a `map<string,string>` of the environment.  Then everytime your code calls `setenv` as a result of a shell command, update your map.

Comment: @selbie that was what I was doing before but with a vector in a different way but wanted to use the environment that the process gave to me rather than manage one on my own. I didn't realize this mistake until I had done all the changes and was just wondering if there was something I was missing and that I didn't have to undo all the changes I just made lol.  Oh well, thank though~!

Answer (score 1):

`envp` is not a standard argument to `main`. Its meaning depends on the implementation. It seems on your implrmentation `envp` is the original environment as it was when `main` was called.

As a guess: Windows? Because its environment is really `wchar_t[]`, not `char []`. That means the `char** envp` result is converted from `wchar_t**`.

Comment: `setenv` is a POSIX function so this question is probably not about Windows at all.

Comment: What @DietrichEpp said. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) would have you believe that

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

has an up to date cstring array of environment variables.

```
extern char ** environ;
```